# How do I test what my Ruby code does when it catches a symbol? (RSpec)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm working on a Sale flow that involves a few steps - discount, verification, payment, delivery, etc. If something goes wrong during the process, I want to be able to abort the operation, but still return the Sale object to the caller.

The code works just fine, using throw/catch (but I'd be happy to use raise/rescue if it would help.) The problem is testing it — ideally, I'd be able to write a test that says "if something goes wrong, the sale stops processing". Instead, it seems like the best I can do is say "If something goes wrong, it throws :done" or "If something goes wrong in step 2, it doesn't complete Steps 3 and 4". Is there any other way to approach this test that can actually test the more general case?

Here's a slightly altered version of the code I'm working with. Methods with bangs are methods that could potentially call `fail!` or `succeed!`

```
# sale.rb
class Sale
  attr_accessor :status, :amount, :discount_code

  def process!
    catch :done do
      validate_params!
      amount = apply_code!(discount_code)
      verify_delivery!
      charge_money!
      deliver_goods!
    end

    self
  end

  def fail!(error_message: nil)
    Rails.logger.error(error_message)
    status = :failure
    throw :done
  end

  def succeed!
    status = :success
    throw :done
  end
end
```

And an example of the kind of RSpec test I'd like to avoid:

```
# sale_spec.rb
describe 'Sale' do
  describe '#process!' do
    context 'when verification fails' do
      before do
        allow(sale).to receive(:verify_delivery) { sale.fail! }
      end

      it "doesn't charge money" do
        expect(sale).to_not receive(:charge_money!)
        sale.process!
      end

      it "doesn't deliver the goods" do
        expect(sale).to_not receive(:deliver_goods!)
        sale.process!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way I can test this more generally?

Comment: Why don't you test the actual results? Transactions in a db, difference in balances, etc.?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I could (and I do in other places), but, unless I misunderstand what you mean, to do that here would mean a lot of new tests to maintain — if Step 1 fails, we don't get the results of Steps 1-5; if Step 2 fails, we do get the results of Step 1, but not the results of Steps 2-5, etc, etc. I want to test generally that "if the operation fails, we stop".

Comment: "if the operation fails, we stop" - but how do you define "we stop"? Your test with "expect to not receive" expectations actually looks quite sensible to me.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's a great question. I don't have a good code definition for it yet. I think if I isolated the catch block in its own method, I might be able to get closer. 

    def process!
      perform_sale!
      self
    end

    def perform_sale!
      catch :done
        ...various actions...
      end
    end

Then I'd define "we stop" as "we step out of the perform_sale! method".

The existing test feels like verifying an array of values by testing the third element of the array. It works now, but someone could easily break the code without breaking the test.

Comment: When you say "if something goes wrong, the sale stops processing", it sound something that doesn't belong to a model spec, it sounds as something viewed as a user, maybe you have to think this spec as a feature spec (define a few cases of things that make it "go wrong" and expect the result on the page that tells you it stopped processing the sale) and not a model unit test.

Answer (score 1):

I won't present the solution for your particular code, but lets consider the problem in general. You have a group of actions that together are responsible for the sale process. The solution is to make each action independent and put them into flow. Each action could be revertable in case of error. In such case the whole process would stop on the error instruction and step back action by action by invoking their revert methods. All actions should share some context where you could store objects (and pass them to the next interactor). This way you would be able to mark the process as failed and have an access to its context later.

There is a great lib that you should check - https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor. Basically you can define interactors as blocks and then form an organizer from those classes. It allows you to use `FooOrganizer.call(some_context)` which will return a context object. This context object responds to `success?` and `failure?` methods (you can call `context.fail!` inside any interactor to stop proceeding, marking the process as failed and performing a rollback). You have also access to objects inside the context from outside (so you can access to the sale object later).

In this approach you can just test if organizer was successful (or not) and / or check proceeded objects in its context.

Comment: Thanks @smefju. An interesting approach, but I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around it. It sounds like you're saying that the difficulty in testing my original approach is that the outcome is different, depending on when the failure occurs, whereas with an atomic operation like the one you're describing, the results will always be the same, making testing much easier. Am I understanding you right?

Comment: In described approach you can choose if you want to only test that the whole process has failed and the proceeded object is in some specific state OR you can test each action separately and then the whole organizer (what if each interactor fails) + object's state.

Comment: @arthurlewis does it answers your question or perhaps you expected something else?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm not sure if this answers my question. The interactor pattern you're describing doesn't seem that different from what I'm already doing. From a testing perspective, my options would still be to test a single final state by making every action revertible, or to test the individual state for each action where the process would fail. It seems like the big win with this pattern might be that I can test a single state per action, rather than expecting multiple messages. Is that the idea?

Comment: You have asked for a test that says "if something goes wrong, the sale stops processing" - in my post I have described such solution. Of course, you can implement it your self. The basic idea is to implement some `success?` method for the whole workflow (which performs all actions) that returns general state of operation (to avoid rescuing exception from outside of class). Second thing that you need (as written in question) is sale object. It needs to be a global object accessible from outside inside that container (to test it after asserting that `success?` returned `false`).

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it sounds like what you're describing is a test that says "If something goes wrong, the sale is marked as failed." That's a test I already have. I'm looking for a test that says "For a set of arbitrary actions, if fail! is called during any action, none of the subsequent actions are called." It's almost like I just want to test that all the actions in the method are wrapped in a catch block, or at least perform as if they were. To test that through state would mean testing the individual expected state for each possible failure, instead of the bigger structure.

Comment: To consider something an answer to my question, I think I'd expect to see either "here's how you test that bigger structure" or "here's why you can't or shouldn't test that bigger structure".